# Rocketchat-server proces running on my Ubuntu 20.04 server?? (NEVER INSTALLED)

Tags: server, snap

**node /snap/rocketchat-server/1455/main.js**     is running on my ubuntu server when I issue htop command, I never installed it, didn't know what it was and am never gonna use it.

It's using 7% of my memory.

Edit: I also see nextcloud and sabnzbd in the list

I want to delete it but how?

HTop screenshot showing the running process(es):

[image: Screenshot of HTOP]

Answer (score 1):

SOMEONE installed `rocketchat-server` on your system via snaps.  Likely the same with the other ones as well, which means that if YOU didn't do it another sysadmin of your box did (and if there's no other admins on your machine, then you can assume the system is compromised)

You can purge these with `sudo snap remove rocketchat-server nextcloud sabnzbd`

I would then suggest you start a heavy audit of your system and assume it's been compromised.  Get any data you want off the system (so you can restore it later), then **nuke the system and reinstall cleanly** and harden the server before restoring your data.

Start with these hardening steps:

1. **DO NOT** allow PasswordAuthentication on SSH ports
2. Set up a firewall to block access to ports from the outside
3. ONLY use SSH key authentication to SSH into your system
4. Set up `fail2ban`
5. DO NOT give any users `sudo` permissions if there's multiple users on the system.

Comment: 2. A firewall is not necessary if you never install services when they are not needed on your server. All services running on your server should be secured before allowing an internet connection to them.

Comment: @HappyTux given that OP says they never installed things, it's a standard suggestion.  Also given they refer to it as a 'server' and these services were running without their knowledge, it's fairly safe to assume that someone gained remote access to the system without their knowledge and installed these.  The 'hardening' steps are "Best Practices" regardless of server use case.

Comment: No doubt about it the server has been owned. Firewalls are only necessary when you run services you have no clue about they should never be running for just this reason. A server is there to serve up their services on the machine. Without them being secured it will do nothing for you. It only protects the clueless who have services running that should not be running. You want the server to be serving up what you want it to serve, those ports are always going to be open. Security theatre at its best to give the clueless a feel good feeling by thinking they have done something good...

Answer (score 0):

Allright guys,

So thank you for all the the answers, but somehow I think I accidentally installed these snaps on installation! Because the server is fairly fresh, practically nothing was running on it aside for a Local/Github webdev environment. Check the picture, it might just be I got it with installation.

Grtz Mex

[Ubuntu 20.04 server installation snaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldnw1.png)